# How do I add active element to a li in a div?

Tags: html, jquery

I have this structure for a widget right here and I would like to add `active` class to the `li`.

I have tried to do this but it isn't working and I don't know where the problem is.

```js
var selector = '#recent-posts-5';
var url = window.location.href;
var target = url.split('/');

$(selector).each(function() {
  if ($(this).find('li').attr('href') === ('/' + target[target.length - 1])) {
    $(selector).removeClass('active');
    $(this).removeClass('active').addClass('active');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="recent-posts-5" class="blog_widget widget widget_recent_entries">
  <h5 class="widget-title"><span>Iekārtas</span></h5>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="somelink"></a></li>
    <li><a href="somelink"></a></li>
    <li><a href="somelink"></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: li has no attribute naming href. It should be anchor tag.

Answer (score 1):

The `li` don't have the href, the `a` elements do.

To achieve what you need more simply you can use the `has()` method to determine if the selected element has any links to the given URL and apply the class to it:

```js
var selector = '#recent-posts-5';
var url = window.location.href; // in the snippet this = 'https://stacksnippets.net/js'
var target = url.split('/'); 

$(selector).removeClass('active').has(`a[href="/${target[target.length - 1]}"]`).addClass('active');
```

```css
.active,
.active a {
  color: #C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="recent-posts-5" class="blog_widget widget widget_recent_entries">
  <h5 class="widget-title"><span>Iekārtas</span></h5>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/js">Lorem</a></li>
    <li><a href="somelink">Ipsum</a></li>
    <li><a href="somelink">Dolor</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="recent-posts-6" class="blog_widget widget widget_recent_entries">
  <h5 class="widget-title"><span>Iekārtas</span></h5>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/js">Lorem</a></li>
    <li><a href="somelink">Ipsum</a></li>
    <li><a href="somelink">Dolor</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I think `$("a[href='/"+target+"']",selector).addClass('active');` is enough

Comment: Possible, but I left it in case the class exists on the element by default.

Answer (score 0):

You need to target the link in the LI

You likely wanted

```js
var selector = '#recent-posts-5 ul li';
var url = "https://www.aaa.com/somelink2"; // window.location.href;
var target = url.split('/').pop()
$(selector).removeClass('active'); // is that even needed?
$("a[href='/"+target+"']",selector).addClass('active');
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.active {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="recent-posts-5" class="blog_widget widget widget_recent_entries">
  <h5 class="widget-title"><span>Iekārtas</span></h5>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/somelink1">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="/somelink2">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="/somelink3">Link 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

or if you must loop but then this is a DOUBLE waste of time `$(this).removeClass('active').addClass('active');` just  `$(this).addClass('active');`

```js
var selector = '#recent-posts-5 ul li';
var url = "https://www.aaa.com/somelink2"; // window.location.href;
var target = url.split('/');
$(selector).removeClass('active'); // is this even needed?
$(selector).each(function() {
  if ($(this).find('a').attr('href') === ('/' + target[target.length - 1])) {
    $(this).addClass('active');
  }
});
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.active {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="recent-posts-5" class="blog_widget widget widget_recent_entries">
  <h5 class="widget-title"><span>Iekārtas</span></h5>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/somelink1">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="/somelink2">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="/somelink3">Link 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```